# python read data starting with expected line

Tags: python

This is a data.txt file I want to read:

```
####
x y
0 1
1 2
3 4
```

I want to read the data from line 3. My codes is shown following:

```
x = []
y = []
with open('./data.txt', 'r') as f:
    num = 0
    for line in f:
        num += 1
        if num>=3:
            lines = line.split(' ')
            x.append(float(lines[0]))
            y.append(float(lines[1]))
print(x)
print(y)
```

Are there more effective method to read this file without any python packages?

Comment: Can you use `numpy`?

Comment: Use Pandas
`import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("data.txt", sep=" ")
data.iloc[1:,]`

Comment: @Corralien yes, I use `numpy` often

Comment: @ArunSg Ok, it is a very convenient way to do it. Thanks

Comment: `x, y = list(zip(*np.loadtxt('./data.txt', skiprows=2)))`